# Обновление и вставка данных в postgresql на python

Tags: python, json, postgresql, api, update

Есть БД, бд получает данные из некого источника через api json. Данные в бд нужно обновить.
Метод по обновлению должен заменять значения в таблицах если они изменились в api, если добавились новые строки то их нужно вставить в таблицу.

```
data_json  = json.loads(requests.get('https://.....').text)
```

Никак не пойму как сделать UPDATE и одновременно INSERT новой записи в таблицу из объекта API.
Мой код:

```
for raw in data_json:
        cursor.execute(""" UPDATE table_name SET (PARAM1, PARAM2) = ('{0}', ARRAY{1}); """.format(
            raw['param1'],
            raw['param2']    
        ))
```

Но мой код  вместо update новых значений заменяет все строки  в таблице на первую строку из api объекта. В документации postgre приведены примеры с WHERE  но я не пойму как сделать нужное условие, для моего кейса , так как мне нужно сравнить каждое значение с каждой строкой в таблице,  а так же сделать вставку новой строки, если ее нет в таблице. Подскажите пожалуйста как более правильнее решить этот кейс.

Comment: update без where всегда изменяет все строки на те значения которые будут в последней операции update. добавляйте where, которое точно укажет какую запись менять, желательно по какому то уникальному ключу. И если уникальный ключ на таблице есть, то вы можете написать `insert .... on coflict(ключ) do update ...` который вставит то чего нет и обновит то, что есть

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю как добавить конкретный ключ и условие, если все данные у меня берутся динамически, я не знаю их значений. Тем более если делать where по уникальному ключу, то он будет изменять только конкретные столбцы в таблице, то есть для каждого столба мне нужно будет написать отдельный запрос ? Я в примере указал только 2 параметра из api, но у меня их около 30. Мне для каждого параметра писать отдельный sql запрос на обновление ?

Comment: А как вы хотите объяснить БД какую именно запись надо поменять ? БД сама никогда не догадается. Какое отношение имеет ключ к столбцам ? Ключ адресует конкретную запись, которую надо менять, а меняются всегда все указанные в set поля (столбцы), так что будет только один update. Если это будет update то он должен выглядеть примерно как `update table set param1=%s, param2=%s, ... where paramX=%s` под %s тут понимаются параметры, которые может сам подставлять execute, не надо использовать format, он может привести к ошибкам, если в данных окажутся например кавычки

Comment: update table set param1=%s, param2=%s, where paramX=%s . Но как в конкретно моем случае подобрать условие where ?У меня каждое поле содержит уникальное значение. Условие where не может подойти для всех строк таблицы. Значит update вообще не подходит в моем случае ?Я думал над тем чтобы сделать итерацию над объектом api и под каждое его значение выполнять sql запрос значения из таблицы бд для сравнения значений всех полей строки.Проблема в том что может обновиться api значение и его не будет в таблице и сравнить строку я не смогу.Второй вариант вообще пересоздать таблицу, если api обновились

Comment: Вот у вас по api первый раз пришли строки (param1, param2, param3): ('a', 'b', 5), ('a', 'c', 4), а при втором обращении те же строки выглядят как ('a', 'c', 3) , ('b', 'c', 5') (обратите внимание что порядок строк как в api, так и в БД произвольный)А теперь скажите какая конкретно строка как должна измениться и почему. Вам надо внимательно посмотреть данные, получаемые по api и найти поля по которым можно понять что это та же самая запись, какая была получена ранее. Если таковых признаков нет, то единственный способ обновления - это каждый раз очищать таблицу и вставлять все заново